# Ntop-ng unable to login into WebUI?

Tags: 14.04, ntop

I installed latest version of Ntop-NG using following Repository:
http://www.nmon.net/apt-stable/

by the following command in Ubuntu 14.04:
apt-get install ntopng ntopng-data

Now i am unable to login into the WebUI using default admin/admin credentials.
I tried adding new user using Redis also but it did not helped.
No error is displayed but the page simply refreshes after clicking on Login button.

In CLi I see the follwoing line:
"User changed to nobody"

Can this be the issue? Please help me to login into Ntop-ng.

Comment: I can provide more outputs from CLI if required.

Comment: Unable to find any help even on NTOP website or Sourceforge, google, etc

Answer (score 1):

I am able to login properly now.
Did not changed anything.
Just updated few Ubuntu packages.
Dont know what changed.

Comment: Same problem here. I keep having to do fresh installs of ntopng to gain access back in thru web gui. I think there is an issue with the redis-server it uses for authentication, but no log output.